# Change reference of third party dll

Tags: c#, assembly, .net-core, ikvm

I've got a third-party dll named MAF.Core.dll.

This dll is using the NuGet-Package "IKVM" Version 8.1.5717.0.
Unfortunately if I'm using the dll in .net Core, it's not working anymore, because this IKVM version doesn't work in .net Core.

Luckily there's another IKVM version: https://github.com/ikvm-revived/ikvm

But this IKVM-Version has the version 8.5.0.3. Therefore my MAF.Core.dll can't use those new dll's.

Question: How can I use the new IKVM-Dll's for my MAF.Core.dll?

*Specific Version* is set to false and I've also tried to change the app.config like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="IKVM.OpenJDK.Core"
                          publicKeyToken="13235d27fcbfff58"
                          culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="8.1.5717.0"
                         newVersion="8.5.0.3"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages. This makes them harder to read and prevents search engines from indexing the error message.

Comment: I think you have no other choice as to upgrade to a MAF.Core.dll version that's compatible with .Net Core ... maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I don't have the source code of MAF.Core.dll. It's a third party library. Therefore I can't update the references of it.

Comment: have you thought about replacing the library with an alternative?  Do they offer a version of MAF.Core thats compatible with .NET Core?  If the library has been abandoned have you though about JustDecompile by Telerik?  It can decompile the assembly and create a project from the IL.

Comment: Where do you get MAF.Core.dll from?

Comment: @newky2k I've tried that, but I'm getting ~150.000 errors with the csproj file, because it's generating a lot of stuff, which isn't correct (like instead of a method named "init()" it's called "__\u003Cclinit\u003E".

Comment: @Fildor It was a student project. The csproj isn't there anymore. I've just the dll.

Comment: In that case I'd consider it broken and obsolete. Not safe for production at the very least.